# Jekyll (Liquid): Setting post state in included templates

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Maybe this is a case of a Python programmer trying to work with Ruby and maybe this is a ["feature"](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1956) -- I don't know. For the life me I can't figure out how to set state on posts during the rendering process.

I have a `_layout` that just calls `include` twice:

```
{% include templateA %}
{% include templateB %}
```

`templateA` walks the posts and renders *some* of them on the basis of `some_condition`.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% if some_condition %}
   <!-- Render the post -->
{% assign post.rendered = true %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`templateB` attempts to walk the posts and render *the rest*:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% unless post.rendered %}
   <!-- Render the post -->
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This does not work as expected. I have also tried the `{% assign post[rendered] = true %}` syntax. No errors are thrown; just silent failure.

Where am I failing here? Is my mental model for the rendering process just totally wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm don't know jekyll's internals. Perhaps the include sare not run sequencitally, or variable assignment doesn't propagate. How about checking the `some_condition` again inside templateB?

Comment: Yeah, that's the backup plan. It's poor encapsulation, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your first though was nearly ok. The `unless` tag does the contrary of `if`.
But you cannot change jekyll's variables, they are "freezed".

So, this might work :

**templateA**

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if same_condition %}
    <!-- Render the post -->
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

With the same condition `unless` will render posts not rendered by the first loop.

**templateB**

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% unless same_condition %}
    <!-- Render the post -->
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you cite a source in the docs that clearly indicates that the post attributes are "frozen?" I can't find the scoping rules outlined anywhere.

Comment: @BrianTheLion You'll find nothing in the doc about this. It comes from my experience : using Jekyll and reading source code.

Comment: The only thing I've found is a comment from a Shopify Liquid dev [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/302#issuecomment-33076317). You can also read the code like explained [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/302#issuecomment-40442399).